# which is the best programming language to capture Audio & Video (web based)?

Tags: audio, video

I am trying to capture Audio & video inputs from webcam & microphone what would be the best Programming language to use ? ( I also do know that in HTML 5 it can be done easily) but, looking for some other options.

Comment: It depends on your target environments.

Comment: How about all of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out a jQuery plugin called ScriptCam.

It should give the functionality you want and it should work in all environments.